# Upstart script for a transmission-daemon executed as a normal user

Tags: services, scripts, upstart, init, transmission

I have done a script to start transmission-daemon as a normal user:

```
start on filesystem
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 10 5

pre-start script
    test -x /usr/bin/transmission-daemon || { stop; exit 0; }
    test -d /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon || { stop; exit 0; }
end script

exec su -l -c 'transmission-daemon --foreground --config-dir /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon --logfile /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon/daemon.log' user
```

This script works but I see two processes in execution of transmission-daemon:

```
user     5041  0.0  0.0  48556  1516 ?        Ss   01:10   0:00 su -l -c transmission-daemon --foreground --config-dir /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon --logfile /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon/daemon.log user
user     5048  0.5  0.0 150432  2960 ?        Sl   01:10   0:00 transmission-daemon --foreground --config-dir /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon --logfile /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon/daemon.log
```

Is this correct?
Is there another way to execute this better?

Note: *The default startup script of transmission package is disabled*.

**More info**:

If I execute transmission as a daemon (without `foreground`) the problem is the detected PID by init:

```
start on filesystem
stop on runlevel [!2345]

expect fork

pre-start script
    test -x /usr/local/bin/transmission-daemon || { stop; exit 0; }
    test -d /home/mario/.config/transmission-daemon || { stop; exit 0; }
end script

exec sudo -u user transmission-daemon --config-dir /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon --logfile /home/user/.config/transmission-daemon/daemon.log
```

.

```
$ sudo initctl list | grep trans
trans-test start/running, process 3110
```

but really this is the PID of sudo (*finished process*), the transmission-daemon PID is another:

```
$ ps aux 
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
user     3148  0.0  0.0 154848  2708 ?        Ssl  13:33   0:00 transmission-daemon
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you already know about and have disabled the System V startup script that is [installed by default](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/amd64/transmission-daemon/filelist)?

Comment: Yes, the default startup script is disabled and that script doesn't start transmission-daemon with `foreground`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the solution is to start transmission-daemon in foreground (*no expect fork or daemon*) and that `start-stop-daemon` creates the pid file.
The complete script:

```
description "Transmission daemon for user"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0 and runlevel [235])
stop on runlevel [016]

kill timeout 50

respawn

env USER=user
env PIDFILE=/var/run/transmission-user.pid

script
    DAEMON=$(which transmission-daemon) || exit 0
    CONFIGDIR=/home/$USER/.config/transmission-daemon

    exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $USER --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --exec $DAEMON -- -f --config-dir $CONFIGDIR --logfile $CONFIGDIR/daemon.log
end script

post-stop exec rm -f $PIDFILE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `--foreground` is correct—you want upstart to track the progress of your transmission process. To omit `--foreground` add `expect daemon` to the init config which will follow two forks of the process, which is how services daemonize.

Using `start-stop-daemon` is suboptimal as upstart can't watch your process and respawn it as necessary in case of crash, etc.

Here's my config:

```
start on (runlevel [2345] and filesystem and networking)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
kill timeout 30

setuid transmission

exec /usr/bin/transmission-daemon --foreground --config-dir /var/lib/transmission
```

Answer (score 1):

When you start an app with `su -c`, su will wait for the app to terminate. In your case, having added the `--foreground` option, make transmission to not detach from its parent. So you will see `su` as a parent process of `transimssion-daemon` for all the time the latter lives.

If you remove that option, you will see that `su` process will terminate as soon as `transmission-daemon` goes to the background.

Apart from removing that option that seems inopportune for a service, I suggest to use

```
sudo -u <your-user> app-name options
```

instead of `su`, being more close to the Ubuntu way of doing things, and being more simple to manage options without the need to use single quotes.

Comment: But if I supress `foreground`, init detects wrong the process PID. It saves the PID of `sudo` but `sudo` is finished:
`initctl: trans-test start/running, process 3110` but the process has other PID: `user     3148  0.0  0.0 154848  2708 ?        Ssl  13:33   0:00 transmission-daemon`

Comment: An untested alternative could be to get ownership of the executable (`sudo chown $USER:$USER /usr/bin/transmission-daemon`), then make it setuid (`chmod u+s /usr/bin/transmission-daemon`).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me. Tranmission will be executed twice with different users.

Comment: Executed twice, and with different users in addition, is very very strange

Comment: Yes, one transmission-daemon for each system user.

Answer (score -1):

My version:

```
start on (filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

# give time to send info to trackers
kill timeout 30

expect fork
respawn

script
        USER=debian-transmission
        test -f /etc/default/transmission-daemon && . /etc/default/transmission-daemon
        test "$ENABLE_DAEMON" != "0" || exit 0
        exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $USER --exec /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -- $OPTIONS
end script
```

Woks good:

```
root@ubuntu-server:/etc/init# status transmission-daemon
transmission-daemon start/running, process 754
root@ubuntu-server:/etc/init# ps aux|grep [t]ransmission-daemon
torrent    754  0.0  1.1  41592  5596 ?        Ssl  Oct21   0:56 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon --auth --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
```

Comment: This script doesn't work to me: `transmission-simon start/running, process 5880` but process 5880 doesn't exist. I think upstart takes the PID of start-stop-daemon command instead of the transmission-daemon.